# Is there a way to use Autowired constructor in JUnit test using Spring or Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, junit, integration-testing, autowired

Assume, that I have a test configuration with several Spring beans, that are actually mocked and I want to specify the behavior of those mocks inside JUnit test suite.

```
@Profile("TestProfile")
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "some.cool.package.*"})
public class IntegrationTestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public Cool cool() {
        return Mockito.mock(Cool.class);
    }
}

// ...

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("TestProfile")
public class CoolIntegrationTest {

    private final Cool cool;

    @Autowired
    public CoolIntegrationTest(Cool cool) {
        this.cool = cool;
    }

    @Test
    public void testCoolBehavior {
        when(cool.calculateSomeCoolStuff()).thenReturn(42);
        // etc
    }
}
```

If I run this test I will get:

```
java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor
```

I know the workaround like use Autowired fields in tests, but I wonder **if there a way to use Autowired annotation in JUnit tests?**

Answer (score 1):

It's not the autowiring that's the problem, it's the no-arg constructor. JUnit test classes should have a single, no argument constructor. To achieve what you are attempting to do, you should do the following:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("TestProfile")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {IntegrationTestConfiguration.class})
public class CoolIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private final Cool cool;

    @Test
    public void testCoolBehavior {
        when(cool.calculateSomeCoolStuff()).thenReturn(42);
        // etc
    }
}
```

The contextConfiguration annotation tells spring which config to use for the test, and autowiring the field instead of the constructor will allow you to test your spring bean.

Answer (score 1):

To run a test using Spring you have to add `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and make sure that your class is added to the classpath. There are a few ways to do it. I.e. 
Add class to MVC configuration `@WebMvcTest({Class1.class, Class2.class})` or use `@ContextConfiguration`.

But I see your code, I suppose that it would be easier just use `@Mock` or `@MockBean` to mock your beans. It will be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

JUnit requires the Test case to have a no-arg constructor, so, since you don't have one, the exception happens before the wiring process.

So Constructor-Autowiring just doesn't work in this case.

So what to do?

There are many approaches:

The easiest one (since you have spring) is taking advantage of @MockBean annotation:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
 ....
class MyTest {

   @MockBean
   private Cool cool;

   @Test
   void testMe() {
      assert(cool!= null); // its a mock actually
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JUnit 5, Spring Boot 3.1.2. Tests passed with non-null repository:

```
@SpringBootTest
class ProfileControllerTest {
  private final UserRepository repository;

  @Autowired
  public ProfileControllerTest(UserRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
  }

  @Test
  void get() throws Exception {
    System.out.println(repository);
  }
}
```

`@Autowired` must present for constructor

Answer (score -1):

Besides args constructor you need to have additional one no-args constructor. Try add it and check if this exception still occurcs.

```
@Autowired
public CoolIntegrationTest(Cool cool) {
        this.cool = cool;
    }

public CoolIntegrationTest() {}
```

Comment: I've tried this approach and got other exception:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Test class can only have one constructor

Comment: This will not work, because test class can have only one constructor